# CakePHP load generic Model and echo the displayField

Tags: php, cakephp, generics, model

I am trying to load a generic Model in CakePHP.

What I am trying to achieve now is to load the history table and print it with its displayField and a html-link to that object.

Example-Data:

```
Table: History
id, model, entity_id
1 , User,  123
2 , Files, 345

Table: Users
id,  name
123, 'Steve'

Table: Files
id,  filename,   filesize
345, 'test.txt', 666
```

When I print my history now I need something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>                               //id of history
  <td><a href="/users/123">Steve</a></td>  //link to user
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><a href="/files/345">test.txt</a></td> //link to file
<tr>
```

User should show the "name" and Files should show the "filename".
Thats why I would like to use the displayField I set in the Model.

I thought I might try it with this code:

```
$this->loadModel('Users');
$this->loadModel('Files');
foreach($historyEntries as $entry){
    $genericModel = $this->$entry['HistoryEntry']['model']->find('all');
}
```

But this code tells me that a 'Users-Helper' is missing.
Any ideas how to get this to work?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your model name should be `User`, not `Users`. (Same for `Files`)

Change to

```
$this->loadModel('User');
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I got it like 'User' and 'File'.
That is not the Problem.

Comment: can you paste more of the controller code? (and also the user model)

Answer (score 0):

Sure.
This is pretty much all the code I have:

```
//Files Model
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
    class Files extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'filename';
}

//Users Model
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Files extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'name';
}
//History Model
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class History extends AppModel {
}
//History Controller
public function index(){
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $this->loadModel('Files');
    $historyEntries = $this->History->find('all');
    $result = array();
    foreach($historyEntries as $entry){
        //1. How do I load the generic Model? 
        $genericModel = $this->$entry['History']['model']->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Article.id' => $entry['History']['entity_id'])));
        //2. How do I access the DisplayField of this generic Model
        array_push($result,$genericModel['displayField']);
    }
    $this->set('historyEntries',$result);
}
```